# switch to editable mode in applicable cell in React ag-grid on click of check box

Tags: reactjs, row, selection, ag-grid

I am new to ag-grid and working on implementing a requirement.I have 3 columns and 2 of them are editable. My first column contains a checkbox, on check of which i need to convert the two columns to editable.

Please note i am using ag-grid reactjs version.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a working example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem more or less.. and the solution I found involved a lot of digging around the source. I don't know if there is a better (non-hacky) way of doing this.. but..

I've hooked in to the "onRowClicked" event.

```
onRowClicked(params) {
  const clickedRow = params.api.rowRenderer.renderedRows[params.rowIndex]
  clickedRow.renderedCells.myColId1.startEditingIfEnabled()
  clickedRow.renderedCells.myColId2.startEditingIfEnabled()
  // where myColID1/2 are from the colDef
}
```

It's probably too late - but it works on my machine.

Comment: tried this but if click on a different cell with a checkbox and my editable field is in a different column, when I run your code, it wont focus on that editable field.